# Ensuring settings and mapping are set on index in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

In order to ensure that my Elasticsearch index has the right settings and mapping I have the following code:

```
if (client.admin().indices().prepareExists(Index).execute().actionGet().exists()) {            
    client.admin().indices().prepareClose(Index).execute().actionGet();
    client.admin().indices().prepareUpdateSettings(Index).setSettings(settings.string()).execute().actionGet();
    client.admin().indices().prepareOpen(Index).execute().actionGet();
    client.admin().indices().prepareDeleteMapping(Index).setType(Type).execute().actionGet();
    client.admin().indices().preparePutMapping(Index).setType(Type).setSource(mapping).execute().actionGet();
} else {
    client.admin().indices().prepareCreate(Index).addMapping(Type, mapping).setSettings(settings).execute().actionGet();
}
```

It seems a bit silly to update the settings and mapping even if they are already fine. I do not know how to do stuff in a more clever way though. Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot,

Stine

Comment: Can't you just pass settings and mapping once while creating the index ?

Comment: My problem is that the indexes are already created and being used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can retrieve current settings and mappings and make sure that they are correct before trying to update them.

```
ClusterStateResponse response = client.admin().cluster().prepareState()                
    .setFilterAll()
    .setFilterMetaData(false)
    .setFilterIndices(index)
    .execute().actionGet();
IndexMetaData indexMetaData = response.state().metaData().index(index);
Settings settings = indexMetaData.settings();
// Verify settings
MappingMetaData mapping = indexMetaData.mappings().get(type);
// Verify mapping
```